# jQuery Countdown Not Working?

Tags: jquery, html, countdown

I am currently using this jQuery script on GitHub: https://github.com/rendro/countdown/

It is setup and shows the countdown with just zeros currently. I am trying to change the date to see if it actually counts down properly but it isn't working.

In the documentation on the GitHub page, it instructed me to change the date, but what I've put in doesn't seem to actually change the date.

Code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.countdown').countdown({
        date: "June 7, 2087 15:03:26"
    });
});
</script>
```

The part where I display the countdown is like this:

```
<div class="countdown styled"></div>
```

It might just be a simple mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out!

If anyone is able to help me than thankyou! And if you need more information, just let me know!

Comment: Do you have libraries reference properly? I see, that can be the only issue.

Comment: If it weren't referenced properly I don't believe it would show up with the zeros, but I have a pastebin of the whole file if you want to check it out further. http://pastebin.com/hi2PCbyE Also, the console doesn't output any issues or anything which is weird.

Comment: Run index.html from example from downloaded files, and you can follow this file.

Comment: What do you mean @BhavinPanchani, sorry just a bit confused. Edit: If you mean the index.html in the examples on the github, then I see it, but I just don't understand what to do from there.

Comment: Run it, you will see everything works fine, you can follow the code and js path from this file.

Comment: I see that everything works fine, but I am not rebuilding my whole page based on that. I am just wondering what is wrong with my current code and why its not working.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with other javascript code on your website. the code you posted above looks fine to me. I suggest you to use a tool like firebug to and take a look into the console.

Answer (score 0):

I use counter script from https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown

I had similar issue and spent an hour to make counter work.

Below js code may help someone.

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined) {
$(function() {
    $('#counter').countdown('2018/10/15').on("update.countdown", function(event) {
        $('#day').text(event.strftime('%D'));
        $('#hour').text(event.strftime('%H'));
        $('#minute').text(event.strftime('%M'));
        $('#second').text(event.strftime('%S'));
    });
});
})(window, document, window.jQuery);
```